# Different font in the same paragraph?

Tags: fonts

[image]

Can anyone tell me how do you get different font in the same paragraph like in this paragraph for function name?

Answer (score 6):

As you are not providing any `MWE`, I assumed that you are using standard class file and fonts and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for
test. This is for test. This is for test. This is for test. This is
for test. \texttt{This is for test}. This is for test. 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Other tag to get different `fonts` in a same paragraph: `\textsf`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Minimal example here.I suggest submit minimal example code when you ask a question at **Tex**, then could i provide a precise solution to your question.

I use `{}` to isolate the environment of the sentence and the paragraph, and provide the sentence with its own font.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
This document is a sample document to 
test font families and font typefaces.{\fontfamily{qcr}\selectfont
This text uses a different font for function().}This document is a sample document to 
test font families and font typefaces.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hope can use `\texttt` instead of `\fontfamily....`

Answer (score 1):

The provided text fragment shows that the commands from a code are given as verbatim. So why not use the `\verb*` command to achieve the same effect as the answers above?

```
\documentclass\[12pt\]{article}

\usepackage\[a4paper,text={18.0cm,26cm},top=2.0cm,left=2.0cm\]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    
    In a text about coding, explaining how code can be used to create programs, macro's, templates and such, it is often required to give a code command in a different font than the rest of the sentence or paragraph as is shown in the text image in the question, where a typewriter font is used inside a serif font text fragment.
    
    There are serveral options to do that. For example the code:
    
    \verb*|{\fontfamily{<fontname>}\selectfont command or coding text}| will set the \textsf{command or coding text} in a different font in midsentence. The same reult can be obtained using commands like \verb*|\textsf| -- printing in a sans serif font, \verb*|\texttt| -- printing in a typewriter font or \verb*|\textrm| --printing in a serif font. Whereas \verb*|\fontfamily{<name>} \selectfont| will give you more freedom about the font used to typeset these parts, the latter trio is always present even when no font is specifically loaded in the preamble, like in this example.
    
    The code words in the provided text fragment are actually set as verbatim. As you can see in the MWE of this example, the command \verb*~\verb*|text|~ is used to change the font of a (group of) words midsentence. \verb*~\verb*|text|~ essentially typesets the text between the bars in typewriter font, so it is equivalent to using \verb*|\texttt{text}|. Note that \verb*|\verb*| doesn't use curly brackets, but a set of characters to denote the start and end of the text to be printen verbatim. In this MWE the characters bar and tilde are used to do that.
    
\end{document}
```

(Have no idea why the quality of the image is so bad. The PDF is perfect, the JPG not)
[image]